# What is relation between Tomcat and ( MOM or CORBA )

Tags: tomcat, networking, corba, mom

I know tomcat is server and mom is for transport between client and server.
So how they are related ? Is tomcat providing in built service for transport or we have to specify we have to use mom or corba for transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't related. Tomcat is a specialized form of HTTP server. There is no MOM layer required, unless you count an HTTP library as MOM. I don't. It doesn't use CORBA either.